# Drawing a picture in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

How Can I draw picture like this in Latex ?
[image]

Comment: Welcome! You are more likely to get help if you post a minimal working example showing the code you've got so far and ask for help with a specific problem. Do-it-for-mes are not really fair questions for this site. If you really want somebody to do everything for you, it is best to adjust your desires so that you want help with an image which is especially appealing, challenging, cute or humorous. Ducks, witches and cats seem to go down well, along with things which can be drawn using especially complex combinations of `\foreach` loops. Trees of any kind are always popular.

Comment: I am not clear why you tagged this `decorations`, so I've removed that. I guess from your tags that you want to use Ti*k*Z, though it is not clear why. However, this would be straightforward to draw in PGF/Ti*k*Z, so it would not be a bad choice if that's your cup of tea.

Comment: I am new to latex .So i want a reference or book so that i can draw this .

Comment: (1) For Ti*k*Z, start with the tutorials in the manual. (2) If you are new to LaTeX, don't even consider drawing it in LaTeX. Use an external programme and `\includegraphics`. You have enough to deal with without trying to learn Ti*k*Z at the same time as you are trying to learn LaTeX. Give yourself a break: time enough to learn Ti*k*Z when you are confident in LaTeX. But if you insist, the tutorials are the place to start.

Comment: This is *the* reference: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: But also have a look at `pgfplots`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{axis/.style={draw=gray, ->, thin}, axis scale/.style={x=4cm/405, y=1cm},
  shorten/.style={shorten >=#1, shorten <=#1}, shorten/.default=1mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round, >=Triangle, font=\small]
\draw [axis, axis scale] (-420, 0) -- (420, 0) node [at end, below] {$x$};
\draw [axis, axis scale] (0, -0.5) -- (0, 2)   node [at end, left]  {$y$};
\draw [thick, axis scale] 
  plot [domain=-420:420, samples=100, smooth] (\x, 0.5*cos \x);
\draw [axis scale, shift=(90:1)] 
  plot [domain=-420:420, samples=60, smooth, ycomb] (\x, 0.5*cos \x - 1);
\node at (0, 1) [above, fill=white] {The applied external pressure};
\node [align=center, anchor=north west] (free-surface-label)
  at (-4, -1) {The initial free surface \\ $y=\eta(x,0)=0$};
\node [align=center, anchor=north east] (subsequent-surface-label)
  at (4, -1) {The subsequent free surface \\ $y=\eta(x,t)=0$};
\draw [->, shorten] ([axis scale]-380, 0) -- (free-surface-label);
\draw [->, shorten] ([axis scale]380, 0.5*cos 380) -- (subsequent-surface-label);
\tikzset{shift=(270:4)}
\draw [thick, axis scale] 
  plot [domain=-420:420, samples=200] (\x, {abs(\x) >= 180 ? 0 : 1.5*(0.81 - (\x/200)^2)});
\node at (0,0) [align=center] {$y=-h + \varepsilon(k, x)$ \\ The non-horizontal bottom};
\draw [axis scale, <->, shorten] (-420,0) -- (-420,4) node [midway, left] {$h$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code with `pstricks`. You must launch the compiler with the `--enable-write18` switch for MiKTeX, `-shell-escape` for TeX Live or MacTeX.

```
\documentclass[pdf, svgnames, x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic, plotpoints=200, arrowinset=0.12, linejoin=1}
\small
\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-8)(7.5,4)
    \uput[dl](0,0){$ O $}
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillstyle=vlines, hatchangle=0, hatchwidth=0.4pt, hatchsep=4pt, linestyle=none]{
        \psplot{-7.5}{7.5}{cos(x)}\psline(7.5,1.8)(-7.5,1.8)}
    \psplot[linecolor=IndianRed, linewidth=1.2pt, plotstyle=curve, plotpoints=200]{-7.5}{7.5}{cos(x)}\closepath
    \psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-7.5,-1)(7.5,4)[$x$,-110][$y$, -160]
    \uput[dl](0,0){$ O $}
    \pnodes(-7,0){H}(-7,-5.5){K}(-6,0){Ini}(7,0.75){Sub}
    \psset{nodesep=3pt}
    \ncline[arrows=<->]{H}{K}\ncput*{$ h $}
    \psline(-7.5,-5.5)(-3,-5.5)\psparabola(-3,-5.5)(0,-3)\psline(3,-5.5)(7.5,-5.5)
    \rput(0,-5.5){\Centerstack{$ y = -h + kε(x)$\\ The non-horizontal bottom}}
    \rput(0,2.5){\psframebox[linestyle = none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white]{The applied external pressure}}
    \psnode(-4.2,-2.2){IFS}{\Centerstack{The initial free surface\\ $ y = η(x, 0) = 0$}}
    \ncline[arrows=->]{Ini}{IFS}
    \psnode(4.2,-2.2){SFS}{\Centerstack{The subsequent free surface\\ $ y = η(x, t)$}}
    \ncline[arrows=->]{Sub}{SFS}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you . What is the program did you use ?

Comment: Just `pdflatex`. `pstricks` is a series of packages which act as an interface between LaTeX and Adobe Postscript.